# Calculate Throughput from tomcat response time

Tags: performance, tomcat, jmeter

I am hitting tomcat with certain load and I can see tomcat response time in tomcat's localhost_access_log as below:

```
[28/Oct/2015:00:00:00 +0530] "POST /service/abcd/getService HTTP/1.1" 200 122 3
```

where 3 is the tomcat response time in ms.

So can i say that the TPS of my tomcat is:

```
In 0.3 ms total request served = 1
In 1 sec total request served = (1/0.3)*1000 = ~3333
```

If this is not correct. Can you please confirm a way to find tomcat Throughput from tomcat logs.

Comment: What you are doing is correct. Throughput is completions per unit time. (req/sec or req/min or page/sec etc.) In this case for your test it is correct that ~3333 req/sec is throughput. Problem is load is very small and not a real life thus your throughput doesn't represent actual throughput of your system. If you want to find that then put a realistic load on system then calculate it.

Comment: thanks... I will be hitting multiple threads to simulate load...

Answer (score 0):

To compute throughput the best thing is to use JMeter results instead of jmeter logs:

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/automatically-generating-nice-graphs-at-end-of-your-load-test-with-apache-jmeter-and-jmeter-plugins/

Or you can use this custom version of JMeter that contains a new Reporting feature:

```
https://github.com/ubikloadpack/jmeter/releases/tag/2.14-preview-ubikloapack-beta
```

You can see what it shows here:

```
http://ubikloadpack.com/donations/dashboard/
```

This feature is being donated to JMeter, if you feel it's useful, then : - Register at http://jmeter.apache.org/mail2.html - The send a mail saying you like it here to JMeter Users List user at jmeter.apache.org with subject "Re: Donation of a New Dashboard for JMeter : Questions and more"

Comment: Hi, I am using tomcat logs. Can you please confirm in terms of tomcat. I am not using any additional tool to simulate load

Comment: You're using JMeter to load test right ? So I answered on JMeter topic, this is how load test results must be reported

Comment: I am using my sqmple script to put load on tomcat. But not using jmeter.

Comment: In this case, question should not be tagged jmeter. But anyway you should be using JMeter and using its reporting feature instead of manually trying to compute numbers.